# pytils ru_strftime: russian month case at django templates

Tags: django, templates, date

How can I get russian month in subjective case?
This code:
    {{date|ru_strftime:"%B, %Y"}}
gives "февраля, 2014".
But I need "Февраль, 2014":

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use pytils in this case, just use the localized formatting by datetime module:

```
>>>import datetime, locale

>>>locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'russian_russia')
>>>datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%B, %Y")
'Февраль 2015'
```

Comment: I changed locale in my ubuntu (It was set to ukrainian):                                                                          >>sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8 .
Added to /etc/environment lines:    
>>LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
>>LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8  .
Without reboot:
    export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
    export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8     .                                                               Then set locale as you said:                                            >>locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')